# WebMvcTest with real service implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockmvc

how can I create a "quasi" MVC integration test in Spring Boot. I would like to use my real implementation of a service, but I can't mange to do it. How can I inject real implementation instead of a mock.
My classes look like this

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DashboardController {

    private final RolesManagerService rolesManagerService;
    private final ServletRequestManagerService servletRequestManagerService;

    @GetMapping({"/", "/dashboard"})
    public String index(Model model, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        model.addAttribute("canAddNewOrder", rolesManagerService.canRoleAccessApplicationPart(servletRequestManagerService.getRole(httpServletRequest), ApplicationPart.CREATE_NEW_ORDER));
        model.addAttribute("var", "test");
        return "dashboard";
    }
}
```

and the test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = DashboardController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class IndexControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @MockBean
    RolesManagerService rolesManagerService;
    @MockBean
    private ServletRequestManagerService servletRequestManagerService;

    @Test
    void testDashboard() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/dashboard").with(user("admin").password("pass").roles("USER","ADMIN")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("dashboard"))
                .andExpect(xpath("//a").nodeCount(1))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("canAddNewOrder"))
                .andExpect(model().size(2))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("var", equalTo("test")))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("canAddNewOrder", equalTo(false)))
                .andDo(print());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally WebMvcTest will not create a full Spring context with all components (Service etc) injected, but only the Controller you define. Either use a full SpringBootTest, or add something like this in your WebMvcTest class:

```
@TestConfiguration
static class AdditionalTestConfig {
    @Bean
    public RolesManagerService getService() {
        return new RolesManagerService();
    }
}
```

Comment: key phrase is "in your WebMvcTest class", not just in same file. Great solution to a common problem

Comment: Very useful and resolved a similar problem for me. Thanks @Lars Westergren!

Answer (score 0):

By default, components are not scanned when using @WebMvcTest.
So, if you add something like that..

```
@WebMvcTest(ClassicController.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {Service1.class, Dao1.class})
class WebMvcTest10Solution3 {

    @Test
    void test() {
        // your test code
    }

}
```

where Service1 is a component like..

```
@Service
public class Service1 {

    private final Dao1 dao1;
    public Service1(Dao1 dao1) {
        this.dao1 = dao1;
    }

}
```

and Dao component is..

```
@Repository
public class Dao1 {
    
    // some code

}
```

it will do the job.